# How to get SHA of file for specific Git commit?

Tags: git, commit, sha

Is there a way to get SHA of file for specific Git commit?

It's possible with 2 commands:

1. retrieving file `git show COMMIT_VERSION:myfile.txt > ~/tmp/myfile.txt`
2. calculating SHA `git hash-object ./tmp/myfile.txt`

But, maybe there's specific command in Git that does exactly that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git ls-tree COMMIT_VERSION myfile.txt` appears to contain the same result in its third field.

Comment: `git ls-tree COMMIT_VERSION myfile.txt | cut -d' ' -f 3 | cut -d'     ' -f 1` will pull just the exact hash itself on unix-like shells. (the second cut command has a _tab_ character following the -d flag!)